# Storing information from a string datafile in a vector

Tags: python, pandas, string, for-loop

I want to store information from .dat file, which is in ASCII format. The file - as read by pandas - is an array where each element is a string.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C: ...path to datafile")
y = np.zeros(len(df))
for i in range(0, len(df)):
 y[i] = df.iloc[i, 0][113:122]
```

This gives ValueError: could not convert string to float. However

```
y = np.zeros(len(df))
for i in range(0, len(df)):
 y[i] = df.iloc[0, 0][113:122]
```

Works fine. Of course, each element is identical...The problem is with the iteration and the for loop? Replacing the zero elements indidually works too

Comment: please provide a reproducible `df`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this comment. Do you want me to actually post/upload the entire file here? @mozway

Comment: we need to be able to run your code, but we don't have your file so you must provide code to reproduce a minimal example of your `df` object.

Comment: The error indicates that on some lines of the file positions 113:122 don't contain a number. Your second loop just uses line 0 every time, and that line has a number there.

Comment: Try printing `i` in the loop. Then when you get the error, you'll know which line is the problem.